# adding layers to my Leaflet map using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, leaflet

So here is one of my layers:

```
               TurksAndCaicosLayer = L.geoJson(TurksAndCaicos, { 
                    style: {
                        weight:         0.5,
                        color:          'white',
                        fillOpacity:    1,
                        fillColor:      'brown',
                        }})
```

I have 8 of these polygon layers for my Leaflet map. I am trying to construct a loop which will go through the array of my layers and add them to the map, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone spot why?

```
            let layers = [AnguillaLayer, BermudaLayer, BritishVirginIslandsLayer, GibraltarLayer, GuernseyLayer, IsleOfManLayer, JerseyLayer, TurksAndCaicosLayer]

                for (let layer of layers) {

                map.addLayer(layer)}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
layers.forEach(addLayer);

function addLayer(item, index) {
   map.addLayer(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to add your layers to a `layerGroup` and add the `layerGroup` to the map - saves writing an explicit loop.

```
let layers = [AnguillaLayer, BermudaLayer, BritishVirginIslandsLayer, GibraltarLayer, GuernseyLayer, IsleOfManLayer, JerseyLayer, TurksAndCaicosLayer];

let myLayerGroup = L.layerGroup(layers).addTo(map);
```